# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing

Tags: spring, httprequest, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am using the Spring 4 as backend for my angular Application.When the angular app makes a request to the spring app then I am getting an error

```
Access to **XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/AdminController/allAdmins' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**
```

I am using custom filter to validate each user request
Code for my Filter is:

```
    @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            
    //      Ignoring the request URLs
            if (Utils.ignoreURLs(IGNORE_URLS, httpReq.getRequestURI()) == true) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            
    //      Fetching all the header params from request
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) httpReq;
            Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
            String loggedUserId = null;
            String authToken = null;
    
            if (headerNames != null) {
                while (headerNames.nextElement() != null && headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                    
                    loggedUserId = httpRequest.getHeader(Constants.LOGGED_USER_ID);
                    authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN);
                }
            }
            
            if (Utils.isBlank(loggedUserId) == true || Utils.isBlank(authToken) == true) {  
                httpResp.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                mapper.writeValue(httpResp.getWriter(), getErrorDetailsMap());
                return;
            }
ApplicationContext appContext = AppContextConfig.getApplicationContext();
            AccessManager accessManager = (AccessManager) appContext.getBean(AccessManager.class);
            // I am validating authentication token here
            if(accessManager.isValidToken(loggedUserId, authToken) == false) {
                httpResp.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                mapper.writeValue(httpResp.getWriter(), getErrorDetailsMap());
                return; 
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `@CrossOrigin` annotation over the controllers and define this bean in your SecurityConfig:

```
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token", "xsrf-token"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

**edit**

Or maybe the problem is missing headers, in which the following filter should be sufficient.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

Comment: I have already added @CrossOrigin annotation over all the controllers and created the above bean but still getting errors listed below

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/trophy/AdminController/allAdmins. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/trophy/AdminController/allAdmins. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I've added an edit, give it a try..

Comment: hey @k-wasilewski Do I have to write another filter to solve missing headers problem over my existing filter which is validating user auth token?

Comment: No, you don't. Just add these lines to your existing filter.